# jQuery - ensure IDs are unique in inserted markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="section">
    <input type="text" id="myInput">
</div>
```

I am attempting to insert the html contents of this markup after itself, using the jQuery `html()` and `after()` methods:

```
var newSection = $('#section').html();
$('#section').after(newSection);
```

So I'm ending up with something like this:

```
<div id="section">
    <input type="text" id="myInput">
</div>
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

Is there a way I can ensure the IDs of my inputs are unique? I would prefer something like "myInput2" for the input that has been inserted. Thank you.

Comment: If you are inserting the values in a loop just create or use the existing index variable that increments as you loop. Then concatenate the value to each ID you want to be unique.

Comment: Remove the `id` attributes completely. You can use a common class to group the elements instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that keeps your code the same but adds the new element with a unique ID, specifically "myInput2" for the second execution or "myInputN" for whichever number input is being added:

```
var newSection = $("#section").html();
//create new element with unique ID
newSection = $(newSection).attr('id', "myInput" + ($("input[id^=myInput").length + 1));
$("#section").after(newSection);
```

To determine the next unique ID we simply query all the input tags that start with "myInput"

If you actually want new sections with inputs so the input fields appear one after the other (on top of each other) you can use the following approach which will create a new section with a unique ID and a containing input with a new ID:

```
//Create a new section by cloning the first section
var newSection = $("#section").clone();
//Set the new unique ID for the section
$(newSection).attr('id', "section" + ($("div[id^=section").length + 1));
//Set the new unique ID for child input element
$(newSection).find("input").attr('id', "myInput" + ($("input[id^=myInput").length + 1));
//Add the new section last so each section appears in order by ID
$("div[id^=section").last().after(newSection);
```

Comment: I'm attempting this approach and all the code executes fine, but it appears the contents of 'newSection' aren't being changed, as the code remains identical when I insert it.

Comment: Odd, I just tested it with Chrome and Firefox and it resulted in a new section with a new ID.  It assumes the tags and IDs are the same as in your original html snippet, did you has anything changed since then?

Comment: I made a mistake, it is working great. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(selector).length` to check if an element exist. Then you could use a while loop to increment the number on the end if it does.

```
var i = 0;
selector = "#section";
while($(selector + i).length) {
    i++;
}
// selector is now a unique value. append it to the page
```